# Доступность сайта одновременно по HTTP и HTTPS

Tags: http, https

Есть сайт, для него установлен бесплатный сертификат для работы HTTPS.

Можно ли коим-то образом сделать сайт доступным одновременно по HTTP и по HTTPS?

Comment: @Coolmac, да, раздавать на 80 порту с выключенным ssl и на 443 со включенным. Однако я бы не рекомендовал отказываться от ssl-соединения - жрет всего ничего, а душе приятно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, просто нужно настроить апач (или другой веб-сервер).

HTTP работает на 80 порту, а HTTPS работает на 443-м.

В апаче необходимо создать 2 виртуальных хоста, один для 80-го порта, 2-й для 443-го. Для этих виртуальных хостов установить одинаковые настройки (какие вам необходимы), кроме этого, для ВХ на 443-м порту необходимо активировать `SSLEngine`, чтобы иметь возможность соединяться по HTTPS:

```
SSLEngine on

    #путь к сертификату.
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    #путь к ключу
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю вариант для nginx (из [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)):

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ...
}
```